# How would Euclid have proved that $ a \times b = ((ab)/c) \times c$?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, math-history, alternative-proof

The following statement seems too obvious to prove or even to mention:

That the area of a rectangle with side lengths $a$ and $b$ equals the area of a rectangle with side lengths $(ab)/c$ and $c$ for arbitrary $c>0$, i.e.

$$ a \times b = ((ab)/c) \times c$$

(Note that $(ab)/c$ is a shorthand for $a/(c/b)$.)

I wonder how this statement would have been formulated by Euclid and how he would have proved it (as a geometrical statement with geometrical methods).

I guess there is no proposition in Euclid's *Elements* that says exactly this, but maybe there is one which says essentially the same - or there is an easy proof starting from theorems already proved by Euclid.

This is how how I would formulate the statement:

> Consider two figures constructed like this:
>
> [image]
>
> and like that:
>
> [image]
>
> Then they are equal (in size).

Comment: Basically, in Euclid's geometry a rectangle is defined by two sides : $a$ and $b$ (following your example). Thus (IMO) the "algebraic" expression $((a \times b) / c) \times c$ does not makes sense because the "division" of a rectangle $(a \times b)$ by a side $c$ has no "geomteric interpretation". In conclusion, I agree with your assertion that in Euclid's *Elements* we cannot find a proposition  "that says essentially the same".

Comment: I doubt that Eucid proved exactly that as you formulate  it, nor is that a likely construction for him. See https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookII/propII6.html for the flavor of Euclid's treatment of multiplication.

Comment: I consciously wrote $((ab)/c) \times c$ instead of $((a \times b)/c) \times c$ and declared that $(ab)/c$ is a shorthand for another number created by the second construction (two divisions).

Comment: @EthanBolker: It may not be a likely construction for Euclid, but the statement comes quite natural. It's simple and seems provable.

Comment: I agree that it's provable with Euclid's methods. I just don't think he did. I may be wrong, so I didn't post my comment as an answer.

Comment: @EthanBolker: Good to know that it's provable with Euclid's methods - I assumed that. But my question goes further: how? (Maybe it's trivial, but I'm stuck.)

Comment: Sorry I can't help. I find Euclid's arithmetic too arcane to reproduce.

Comment: To be honest: I hoped for a geometrical proof (like his proof of the Pythagorean theorem).

Comment: Not sure if this can help, but consider a line segment $AB$ of length $a+b$ with a point $P$ inside such that $AP=a$ and $PB=b$.  Let $CP$ be an arbitrary line segment such that $C$ is not on the same line as $A,P,B$ and $CP=c$.  Draw a circle $\Gamma$ passing through $A$, $B$, and $C$.  Extend $CP$ to meet $\Gamma$ again at $D$.  We then have by the Power-of-Point Theorem that  $$AP\cdot PB=CP\cdot PD\text{ or }a\cdot b=c\cdot PD\,.$$

Comment: @Batominovski: I'll check it out - if it gives a comprehensible geometrical proof. (I don't have it in mind, I have to see it.)

Comment: Continue from before.  Thus, a line segment $u$ with length $c\cdot PD$ equals the line segment $v$ with length $a\cdot b$.  Taking a homothety $h$ that rescales everything by $\dfrac1c$, we see that $h(u)$ and $h(v)$ are congruent.  That is, $$PD=\frac{ab}{c}\,.$$

Comment: That's it? Nothing more to say, just to figure it out? That would be great!

Comment: What more do you want?  This proof shows that there exists $x$ such that $a\cdot b=c\cdot x$, and this $x$ must equal $\dfrac{ab}{c}$.  And it is done via Euclidean geometry.

Comment: I don't want more! I just wanted a hint how to prove the statement geometrically - without going algebraic. I hope I've found the way - with your help. (As I promised: I'm going to work it out in diagrams - and we/you will see!)

Comment: He def. would not have used the concept (much less the notation) of $ab$ to mean a linear number so that the ratio of rectangular values of $\frac {a\times b}{1 \times 1}$ is equal to the ratio of the linear values of $\frac {ab}{1}$. But he could have said given a rectangle (with sides $a,b$) and a length $c$ there is a rectangle with side $c$ with the same area and that the other side would have a specific length. (And *we* could call that side $d = \frac {ab}c$-- which is really a *definition* for a geometric interpretation of *linear* multiplication.) I think Micah's answer is just that.

Comment: @fleablood: I've got to delve deeper into these arguments. There's a lot of constructions and notations to bring together, e.g. your $\frac{a\times b}{1 \times 1}$ which have to be understood.

Comment: Well if you have a concept that a rectangle with an area of $(2a)\time (3b)$ is somehow $6$ times the area or a rectangle with area $a\times b$.  Then it seems we can compare the area $a\times b$ with the unit square to get $a\times b :: 1\times 1 = r$.  And if we compare the length of lines so that ther is a line with length $d$ and $d:: 1 = r$ then we can use that as a *definition* of what we mean when we say $a\cdot b= d$ where $a,b, d$ are both linear (not area) values. (Otherwise area values and linear values can not be related at all.)

Comment: @fleablood  So, what's the difference?  I demonstrated that there exists a way to geometrically construct $x$ such that $a\cdot b=c\cdot x$.  Thus, you can construct a rectangle with sides $c$ and $x$ to get a rectangle with the same area as a rectangle with sides $a$ and $b$, which is what Hans Stricker wants.  The second comment I made was to say that $x$ is unique and $x=\dfrac{ab}{c}$.  The construction of $x$ involves no algebra.

Comment: " So, what's the difference?"  What's the difference of what? " I demonstrated that there exists a way to ..."  Who said you didn't?  What's your question?  Why are you responding to me?

Comment: @fleablood  Oh, I asked for an opinion.  It seems that the OP thinks that my construction is somehow algebraic.  So, I wanted to get another opinion on why my construction is somehow different from Micah's in terms of how "algebraic" my construction is.

Comment: @Batominovski I think the OP was simply saying he hadn't read through your details enough and is hoping it is geometric in argument (akin to an elements proof).  I don't think he's saying it wasn't. I haven't read your comment in detail but the construction is certainly geometric.  My comment had nothing to do with any proof but was about the concept of using a number value to represent a unit area vs. a unit length.  Which noting rational lengths $a\cdot b::1$ is equal to rational areas $a\times b::1\times 1$ will bridge and allow "algebraic" arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Two thoughts:

Euclid's [Proposition II.14](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookII/propII14.html) is "to construct a square equal to a given rectilinear figure."

Most of the proof consists of showing that any rectangle is equal in area to a square. This follows from the Pythagorean Theorem and an earlier result in the chapter ([Proposition II.5](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookII/propII5.html)) which decomposes a rectangle as the difference of two squares.

It immediately follows that given any rectangle $R$ and any segment $AB$, you can construct another rectangle with side $AB$ and area equal to $R$. I'm not sure how easy it is to see that this rectangle must be the same one as in your construction, though.

Alternately, you could check out the treatment of similarity and area in [Hilbert](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/17384/17384-pdf.pdf?session_id=d1ca0c1fd1b9f17f4ec28ca055c9f58c7e8eb87f) (chapters III and IV). Euclid would have been comfortable with all his constructions (if perhaps not with their interpretations), and he makes extensive use of exactly the sort of parallel-line construction you are using to define multiplication of line segments. I don't think he proves exactly your theorem, but he proves things which I'm sure are equivalent to it with a little work. (In particular, he rigorously proves that area is well-defined, which is sufficient to fill the gap I mentioned in the proof following Euclid — though possibly overkill.)

Comment: Wonderful answer, thanks a lot! (Maybe Proposition II.14 is what I was looking for.)